# ¿Porque al ejecutar esta función no se asigna el valor a la variable dentro de petición ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Estoy creando una función para validar si un código de tienda es válido, para ello, hago una petición a un php que hace la consulta a una tabla sql donde estan las tiendas. La petición se ejecuta de forma correcta, pero cuando recupero la respuesta desde js, quiero asignar un valor "true" a un booleano si la respuesta explicitamente fue "true" (El php imprimirá eso dependiendo de  la consulta).

El inconveniente nace cuando retorno el valor del booleno al llamar a la función JS, pues me doy cuenta que a pesar de que si hay una respuesta "true", el valor de mi variable booleana en js nunca se asigna, es decir, conserva el valor con el que se inizializó.

Trate de declarar la variable global pues leí que para las asignaturas deben de ser globales las variables, pero no funcióno.

Aqui el código:

```
function validarSucursal(economico){
guardarLogUser(codigoEmpleado, "Intentando validar sucursal "+economico+" desde ajax js...");

$.ajax({
  url: raiz+"Paginas/BackEnd/BE_OF_Validaciones.php",
  type: "post",
  data: {
    "funcion": "validarSucursal",
    "codigoEmpleado": codigoEmpleado,
    "sucursal": economico
  },
  error: function(error){
    guardarLogUser(codigoEmpleado, "No se pudo validar la sucursal desde el lado de ajax petition. Causa: "+JSON.stringify(error));
  },
  success: function(respuesta){  
    if(respuesta == "true"){
      retorno = true;
    }else { 
      retorno = false;
    } 
  }
});  
console.log(typeof retorno + " " + retorno);
return retorno; }
```

php que recibe la petición:

```
function validarSucursal($sucursal){
    $sucursalID = $_POST["sucursal"];
    $codigoEmpleado = $_POST["codigoEmpleado"];
    
    $consultaSucursal = "select * from sucursal where idSucursal = $sucursalID";
    guardarLogUser($codigoEmpleado, "Se genera la consulta para validar si la sucursal existe: $consultaSucursal");
    $ejecucionSucursal = mysqli_query(crearConexionMySQL(), $consultaSucursal);
    
    $ipSucursal = "";
    $nombreSucursal = "";

    guardarLogUser($codigoEmpleado, "Intentando recuperar la información de la consulta");
    while($sucursal = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecucionSucursal)){
        $ipSucursal = $sucursal["ip"];
        $nombreSucursal = $sucursal["name"];
    }

    if($ipSucursal == ""){
        guardarLogUser($codigoEmpleado, "La IP de la sucursal ingresada no se valida correctamente desde el php VAlidacon");
        echo "false";
    }else{
        guardarLogUser($codigoEmpleado, "La IP de la sucursal ingresada  se valida correctamente desde el php Validacon. IP: $ipSucursal");
        echo "true";
    }
}

switch (trim($_POST["funcion"])) { 
    case 'validarSucursal':
        guardarLog("OFValidaciones", "Se hizo una petición para una validación. Petición: ".$_POST["funcion"]);
        validarSucursal($_POST["sucursal"]);
        break;
    
    default:
        guardarLog("OFValidaciones", "Se hizo una petición para una validación pero no se ingreso una petición válida. Petición: $funcion");
        break;
}
```

Estoy seguro que php me retorna la petición correcta porque guardo un log por proceso y se mostró el resulado que asigne a acada parte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adicional a eso, cuando imprimo la respuesta que recupera la petición, imprime correctamente "true"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Dónde declaras el valor de `codigoEmpleado` en Javascript?

Comment: Guardo el proceso en el log desde php y desde js tambien. Quiza tu duda es sobre el llamado del metodo guardarLogUser? si es así, perdon por no aclarlo, tengo tambien una función llamada guardarLogUser en js, esta tambien envia una petición al archivo php que ejecuta ese metodo de guar log:

Comment: Por otra parte, Ajax es asíncrono, no te sirve retornar nada desde ese contexto, a no ser que uses un callback. Si quieres cambiar algo, hazlo desde el contexto de Ajax, en la parte de `success` o de `error` o bien desde ese contexto llama a tu otra función, pasándolo el valor que obtuviste dentro de Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón por la que la variable booleana en tu código JavaScript no se está asignando correctamente es porque la función Ajax que estás usando es asíncrona por defecto. Esto significa que la función Ajax se ejecuta en paralelo con el resto del código, y no espera a que la respuesta de la petición sea recibida para continuar con la ejecución.

Para solucionar este problema, debes utilizar la opción "async: false" en tu función Ajax, de modo que la función espere a que la petición sea completada antes de continuar con la ejecución del código. Además, debes declarar la variable "retorno" como global para que pueda ser accedida desde la función Ajax:

```
function validarSucursal(economico) {
    var retorno; // Declarar variable global
    guardarLogUser(codigoEmpleado, "Intentando validar sucursal " + economico + " desde ajax js...");

    $.ajax({
        url: raiz + "Paginas/BackEnd/BE_OF_Validaciones.php",
        type: "post",
        async: false, // Usar opción "async: false" para que la función espere a recibir la respuesta de la petición
        data: {
            "funcion": "validarSucursal",
            "codigoEmpleado": codigoEmpleado,
            "sucursal": economico
        },
        error: function(error) {
            guardarLogUser(codigoEmpleado, "No se pudo validar la sucursal desde el lado de ajax petition. Causa: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        },
        success: function(respuesta) {
            if (respuesta == "true") {
                retorno = true;
            } else {
                retorno = false;
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(typeof retorno + " " + retorno);
    return retorno;
}
```

Con estos cambios, tu función debería funcionar correctamente y asignar el valor correcto a la variable booleana.

Aunque una mejor forma de manejar esto es utilizar un callback o una promesa para recibir el resultado de la petición Ajax.

Por ejemplo, en lugar de declarar una variable global y asignarle el resultado de la petición dentro de la función Ajax, puedes pasar una función como parámetro a la función "validarSucursal" y llamarla desde dentro del bloque "success" de la función Ajax, pasándole el resultado como parámetro:

```
function validarSucursal(economico, callback) {
    guardarLogUser(codigoEmpleado, "Intentando validar sucursal " + economico + " desde ajax js...");

    $.ajax({
        url: raiz + "Paginas/BackEnd/BE_OF_Validaciones.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            "funcion": "validarSucursal",
            "codigoEmpleado": codigoEmpleado,
            "sucursal": economico
        },
        error: function(error) {
            guardarLogUser(codigoEmpleado, "No se pudo validar la sucursal desde el lado de ajax petition. Causa: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        },
        success: function(respuesta) {
            // Llamar a la función callback pasándole el resultado de la petición
            callback(respuesta);
        }
    });
}

// Llamar a la función "validarSucursal" pasando una función como parámetro
validarSucursal(economico, function(resultado) {
    // Asignar el resultado de la petición a una variable
    var retorno = resultado;
    console.log(typeof retorno + " " + retorno);
});
```

De esta forma, puedes recibir el resultado de la petición Ajax de manera asíncrona y utilizarlo en tu código sin necesidad de utilizar variables globales. También puedes utilizar promesas en lugar de callbacks para manejar el resultado de la petición, dependiendo de tus necesidades y preferencias.

Comment: No queda garantizado que esto funcione. Las llamadas a Ajax son asíncronas. Se debe usar un callback o llamar desde dentro del `success`
 a una función, pasándole el dato, tal y como se hace en la parte de `error`.

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta para considerar lo que mencionas.

Comment: Definitivamente la primer alternativa fue la que me funcionó. Ahora bien, cuando intento hacerlo con la segunda forma, (con callback) intente hacer algo como : `console.log(  validarSucursal(sucursal, funtion (res) {return res}  );` pero retorno indefinido, ya luego si imprimo dentro de la petición la respuesta, ahi si se muestra true. ¿Cual crees que puede ser la mejor forma de simplificar el código? Esto porque esa función la usaria en varios fronts distintos.

Comment: si quieres que validarSucursal te retorne el resultado del callback. tendras que trabajar con promesas.

Comment: ¿Soy yo o está respuesta parece una de las que da chatGPT?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax es asíncrono, no te sirve retornar nada desde ese contexto, a no ser que uses un callback.

Si quieres cambiar algo, hazlo desde el contexto de Ajax, en la parte de `success` o de `error` o bien desde ese contexto llama a tu otra función, pasándolo el valor que obtuviste dentro de Ajax.

Por ejemplo:

`validarSucursal()` quedaría así:

```
function validarSucursal(economico){
    guardarLogUser(codigoEmpleado, "Intentando validar sucursal "+economico+" desde ajax js...");
    
    $.ajax({
      url: raiz+"Paginas/BackEnd/BE_OF_Validaciones.php",
      type: "post",
      data: {
        "funcion": "validarSucursal",
        "codigoEmpleado": codigoEmpleado,
        "sucursal": economico
      },
      error: function(error){
        guardarLogUser(codigoEmpleado, "No se pudo validar la sucursal desde el lado de ajax petition. Causa: "+JSON.stringify(error));
      },
      success: function(respuesta){  
        tuOtraFuncion( (respuesta == "true") );
      }
    });  
}
```

Y debes definir otra función, en el `success` la hemos llamado `tuOtraFuncion()`, cámbialo por algo más descriptivo:

```
function tuOtraFuncion(retorno) {
    console.log(`Dato obtenido con seguridad, porque lo pasas desde dentro de Ajax: ${retorno}`);
    //Aquí tendrás lo que obtuviste en Ajax, true o false
}
```

Comment: He intentado esto, ahora si se asigna el valor a la varible. Pero cuando trato de recuperarlo desde mi front esto no me funciona. Lo que hago es llamar a la funcion validarSucursal(), esta llama a la otra funcion la cual settea el valor a la variable,  depues comparo desde front con un if (sucurSalValida == true) ? si : no.  Pero me retorna false

Comment: @Prototipo_99 ya, pero el parámetro se llama `retorno` si observas bien, define el parámetro como `sucurSalValida` y debería funcionar, o sea: `function tuOtraFuncion(sucurSalValida) {` Por otra parte, un `if` mezclado con un ternario no tiene sentido. Si no funciona, muestra cómo tienes la función completamente.

Comment: Establecí metodos setter y getters para intentar recuperarlos desde otro archivo... Me perdere buscanda nuevas alternativas en base a tu apoyo, separar la la asignación en otra función no lo habia hecho. Si logro encontrar algo lo vengo a plasmar para informarles. Muchas graicas